# DB2 Adding word beside function MOD

Tags: db2

I want to add word Week to show as Week then number from function MOD i tried the following

```
select EVENTTIMESTAMP, Year (EVENTTIMESTAMP) as Year, QUARTER (EVENTTIMESTAMP) as Quarter, 'Week' MOD(WEEK(EVENTTIMESTAMP)-1, 13) + 1 as WeekNoQuarter
```

but i get error :

An unexpected token "MOD" was found following ") as Quarter, 'Week'".  Expected tokens may include:  ",".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.16.53

any suggestion on way to put word Week.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In your code you are trying to name a string 'Week' as MOD(WEEK(EVENTTIMESTAMP)-1, 13) + 1 as WeekNoQuarter. Try concatenating ( || ) the String 'Week ' with the calculated value. Since the calculated value is of type int you will have to cast it:

```
'Week ' || cast(MOD(WEEK(EVENTTIMESTAMP)-1, 13) + 1 as char(2)) as WeekNoQua...
```

Comment: You might want to explain what it is that you added there, and what it's doing.